# Symfony2 routing with prefix issue

Tags: symfony

I'm having my sf2 project with an URL looking like `www.example.com/projectname/`

On local environment, I'm not using the `projectname` folder so my routes are directly after the localhost host name. But in prod env, my routes does not work anymore.

I tried adding a prefix value in <kbd>app/config/routing.yml</kbd> but it didn't change anything, I'm having 404 error when trying to access `www.example.com/projectname/route`

Comment: did you clear the caches?

Comment: Is the `web/app.php` file called on your production server?

Answer (score 0):

I asume you can access your application using /web/.

You need to move all contents of the `web` folder to the document root of the prod env and change the relative paths in `app.php`.

Source: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html